# Error creating bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' ,Failed to instantiate [jpa.JpaVendorAdapter], NoClassDefFoundError: SslSocketFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, sslsocketfactory

When I try To Run Cmd >`mvn clean spring-boot:run -DskipTests`

What I have Already Tried

1. Deleted Folder C:\Users\xyz.m2\repository
2. Pom Files Version Conflict
3. Clean Package
4. Delete Project And Try Again

If You Found Problem In reading Check Here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i7_1gn9W6kybhueWU8CmVEByrE6ageNjqlsc4jx4cGA/edit?usp=sharing

```java
[************ Main Class ******************



       package com.sam.resume;

        @SpringBootApplication
        public class CvGcpApplication {

            public static void main(String\[\] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(CvGcpApplication.class, args);
            }

        }

        @RestController
        @Slf4j
        class HomeController{

            @Autowired
            FeedbackRepo feddbackRepo;

            @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
            public ModelAndView index() {
                return new ModelAndView("index");
            }


            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/index")
            public ModelAndView indexu(@RequestParam Map<String , String> reqpar) {

                String companyName = reqpar.get("compnayName");
                String userName = reqpar.get("userName");
                String message = reqpar.get("message");
                String email = reqpar.get("email");
                log.info("email recived: {}", email);


                 Feedback feedback = new Feedback();

                  feedback.setCompanyName(companyName); 
                  feedback.setUserName(userName);
                  feedback.setEmail(email); 
                  feedback.setMessage(message);
                  log.info("message recived: {}", message);
                  feddbackRepo.save(feedback);


                return new ModelAndView("index")  ;

        }
        }

        @Entity
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @ToString
        @Table( name = "feedback")
        class Feedback {

            @Id 
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            int id;

            @Getter@Setter
            String companyName;

            @Getter@Setter
            String userName;


            @Getter@Setter
            String email;

            @Getter@Setter
            String message;

            public Feedback(String companyName, String userName, String email, String message) {
                this.companyName = companyName;
                this.userName = userName;
                this.email = email;
                this.message = message;
            }
        }

        @Transactional
        @Repository
        interface FeedbackRepo extends CrudRepository<Feedback, Integer>{


    }][1]

    '''

 ''' Properties 

    ***********application.properties***********

        spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
        spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
        spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
        spring.cloud.gcp.config.project-id=resume-gcp 
        spring.cloud.gcp.config.timeout-millis=1000
        spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=xyz:asia-south1:springboot-gcp-cloudsql
        spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=xyz
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/xyz?cloudSqlInstance=resume-gcp:asia-south1:springboot-gcp-cloudsql&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSl=false
        spring.datasource.username=root
        spring.datasource.password=root
        spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
        spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
        spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

```
 ****************** Error Log ******************
> 
>  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)
> 
> 2019-07-13 11:45:07.828  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.sam.resume.CvGcpApplication          : Starting CvGcpApplication
> on Blessing t\classes started by Blessing in H:\practice6\cv--gcp)
> 2019-07-13 11:45:07.837  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.sam.resume.CvGcpApplication          : No active profile set,
> falling back t 2019-07-13 11:45:07.975  INFO 14720 --- [ 
> restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools
> property defaults active! Se e' to disable 2019-07-13 11:45:07.975 
> INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related
> logging co erty to 'DEBUG' 2019-07-13 11:45:09.974  INFO 14720 --- [ 
> restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate :
> Bootstrapping Spring Data repositorie 2019-07-13 11:45:10.107  INFO
> 14720 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate :
> Finished Spring Data repository scann . 2019-07-13 11:45:10.800  INFO
> 14720 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker :
> Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.a e
> [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9311d5fa]
> is not eligible for getting proces  not eligible for auto-proxying)
> 2019-07-13 11:45:10.865  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing
> August 2004 2019-07-13 11:45:10.958  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'org.springframework.transaction guration' of type
> [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee7a10fb]
> is BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> 2019-07-13 11:45:11.002  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'org.springframework.hateoas.con
> ngframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dfa5e2d]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostPro
> -proxying) 2019-07-13 11:45:12.255  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
> port(s): 8080 2019-07-13 11:45:12.317  INFO 14720 --- [ 
> restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting
> service [Tomcat] 2019-07-13 11:45:12.317  INFO 14720 --- [ 
> restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting
> Servlet engine: [Apache Tomc 2019-07-13 11:45:12.711  INFO 14720 --- [
> restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one
> JAR was scanned for TLDs g for this logger for a complete list of JARs
> that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded
> JARs during scanning can ime. 2019-07-13 11:45:12.718  INFO 14720 ---
> [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
> Initializing Spring embedded WebAppli 2019-07-13 11:45:12.719  INFO
> 14720 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            :
> Root WebApplicationContext: initializ 2019-07-13 11:45:13.036  INFO
> 14720 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration :
> Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Conne
> tFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=resume-gcp:asia-south1:springboot-gcp-cloudsql&useSSL=false
> with driver 2019-07-13 11:45:13.043  WARN 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration :
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name i configuration 2019-07-13
> 11:45:13.043  WARN 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : spring.datasource.url is
> specified. N 2019-07-13 11:45:13.349  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2019-07-13 11:45:13.515  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL
> instance [res ] via ssl socket. 2019-07-13 11:45:13.517  WARN 14720
> --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context :
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> oconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter
> 0; n s.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean
> with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource
> [org/ HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0;
> nested except anCreationException: Error creating bean with name
> 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigu : Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instan
> rAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/sql/cor
> 2019-07-13 11:45:13.521  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2019-07-13 11:45:13.539  INFO 14720 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
> 
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-07-13 11:45:13.560
> ERROR 14720 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication          
> : Application run failed
> 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> pa onfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter
> 0; nes factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean
> with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource
> [org/sp bernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0;
> nested exceptio CreationException: Error creating bean with name
> 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instanti dapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception;
> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/google/cloud/sql/core/
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
> ~[spring-beans-
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
> ~[spr
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapa
> 1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFact
> .jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
> 1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
> 8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> ~[spring-beans-5
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> ~[sp
> 
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELE
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEAS
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
> ~[spring-context-5
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
> .8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
> ~[spring-context-5.
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java
> .RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
> [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
> [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELE
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
> [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
> [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
> [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at com.sam.resume.CvGcpApplication.main(CvGcpApplication.java:34)
> [classes/:na]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar: Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' d
> amework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory
> rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
> bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [o
> pa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInsta
> rg.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method
> 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefF ketFactory
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
> ~[spring-beans-
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
> ~[spr
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapa
> 1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFact
> .jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
> 1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
> 8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> ~[spring-beans-5
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> ~[sp
> 
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELE
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEAS
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
> ~[spring-beans-5.
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
> ASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
> ~[ E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
> ~[spring-b
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
> ~[spring-beans-
>         ... 24 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path
> figure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation
> via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.bea
> stantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory
> method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang /core/SslSocketFactory
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RE
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
> ~[spr
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapa
> 1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFact
> .jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
> 1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
> 8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> ~[spring-beans-5
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> ~[sp
> 
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELE
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEAS
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
> ~[spring-beans-5.
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
> ASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
> ~[ E]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
> ~[spring-b
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
> ~[spring-beans-
>         ... 38 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Fac ion;
> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/google/cloud/sql/core/SslSocketFactory
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[sprin
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
> ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RE
>         ... 52 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/google/cloud/sql/core/SslSocketFactory
>         at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:70)
> ~[mysql-socket-factory-1.0.11.jar:na]
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactoryWrapper.connect(SocketFactoryWrapper.java:57)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16
>         at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RE
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RE
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfig
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:112)
> ~[spring-bo LEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d50d36a.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter
> -2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d50d36a$$FastClassBySpringCGLI
> ot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
> ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.ja
> 5.1.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d50d36a.jpaVendorAdapter(<gene
> ELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[sprin
>         ... 53 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
> ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>         ... 87 common frames omitted
```